# Cannot connect my Nexus 5X to Windows 10 PC

Tags: windows, usb-drivers, 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-5x

I have got a Google Nexus 5X and I would like to connect it to my Windows 10 PC.

This is not my first Nexus phone and I'm familiar with things related to a computer as a developer.
But I just can't succeed to make my Nexus phone recognized by the Win10 PC.

At work, on my Windows 7 PC, my Nexus is recognized and I can transfer files.

But at home on my Windows 10 PC, drivers installed by Windows are not OK. There is a yellow warning on my device, displayed in the device manager.

I tried to activate the debugging mode (Android developer settings), tried to reboot, to change USB port.
I also tried with the Google USB Drivers. (I also know that by default, on my Marshmallow Nexus 5X, I have to change connection mode "USB charging" to "Transfer files (MTP)").

The cable I use is OK because it works on my Windows 7 PC and I bought it on Google's Store.

I also had a call with Google Tech Support and they just told me that they don't have any solution for my problem, because I have already tried everything they are used to advice.

I just don't know what to do.

My last try, was to install 'Media Feature Pack for Windows 10 N & KN' (it helped me when I wanted to connect my previous Nexus 5 on a Windows 8.1 laptop).

Any suggestion ?

Sorry for my english.

Best regards,

Hellcat8.

Comment: I've done everything you have done, minus contacting Google Support.  Seems that Windows 10 and MTP are the issue, and I am not sure there is an answer right now.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. At least I know that this is not an isolated issue.
Please give a feedback if you find a solution. I'll do it too if I find one.

Comment: Will do.  I've kept my eye out, and will reply back if something is found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I finally found something which helped me.

The **Media Feature Pack for Windows 10 N & KN (all editions)** alias `KB-3010081` is for the **first** version of Windows 10.

But for the Windows 10 with the big update we had a few time ago, there is an update which supersedes the `KB-3010081`.
This is the `KB-3099229` : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3099229.

 Download : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49919

After all my attempts to resolve my problem, this is the thing which did it for me.

I Hope it will helps.

Best regards,

Hellcat

Comment: I initially steered clear of this solution since I am not running a "N" (No Windows Media Player) or "KN" (Korean - No Windows Media Player) version of Windows. However, this turned out to be irrelevant. For whatever reason, the components of Windows that make MTP work were not present until I installed this update, and without MTP, the Android drivers would not install. Thanks a million!

Comment: This solution (and the other one below) work fine for me if I apply them before connecting the device, but once I've plugged the phone into a computer and it has been incorrectly identified, applying the above fix doesn't work.  It doesn't pick up the new drivers because it still associates the device with the wrong ones.  And my usual fixes of removing the device or deleting the driver don't fix this to my surprise.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me (without having to download the media feature pack).

On your phone (after connecting to PC):

1. Open the notifications bar.
2. Tap USB connection notification (USB for charging)
3. Select PTP-option (this one worked for me at least)
4. Done! You can now open your phone on your pc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise N 2016 LTSB. I installed KB-3010081, KB-3099229,  and nothing worked.
I needed to install KB3133719: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3133719/media-feature-pack-for-n-editions-of-windows-10-version-1607